# Text wraps unexpectedly in the mobile version

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, mobile

When a question title is very long, or there are many tags (enough to wrap over multiple lines), it becomes clear that the text wrapping is affected by the `status` block:

[image: Example of the issue caused by having many tags]

[image: Example of the issue caused by a very long question title]

This is caused by `div.status` setting a `margin-right` property, as well as `div.question-title` declaring a `padding-left`.

The simplest fix is to remove the `margin-right` property on the `.status` block (line 378 of all.css) and to change the `padding-left` property on the `.question-title` block (line 399 of all.css) from 40px to 50px, which will result in the items being presented as such:

[image: Example of the solution, without the wrapping issue]

Comment: Looks like a case for responsive text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build. Thanks for providing the solution!